# Why does the route param cause a type error in VS Code?

Tags: typescript, routes, sveltekit

I'm new to Svelte and TypeScript. I'm writing my first app in SvelteKit, and am trying to create a page that has an integer parameter in its route.

Routing structure

```bash
\src
 \app.d.ts
 \params
  \integer.ts
 \routes
   \posts
    \[id=integer]
     \+page.server.ts
     \+page.svelte
```

`app.d.ts`

```js
declare namespace App {
  interface Locals {
    accessToken: string | null,
  }
}
```

`page.server`

```
export function load({ params }) {
  return {
    id: params.id
  };
}
```

`page.svelte`

```html
<script lang="ts">
  export let data;
</script>

<h1>{data.id}</h1>
```

VS Code is complaining about `page.svelte`, specifically that `data.id` is undefined and it infers the type of the `data` object as `{ accessToken: string | null}`

The page works when I navigate to it, but I'd like to get rid of the type error.

Answer (score 0):

ugh... i got it...  the route params come from the `$page` store, not `LayoutServerLoad` data.

I updated `page.svelte` to

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { page } from '$app/stores'; 
</script>

<h1>{$page.params.id}</h1>
```

and everything works, no VSCode errors and no unnecessary server functions.